# Why is this specific if condition never executes ? [if mid < k <= right:]

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

Im trying to solve a [specific leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-duplicate-number/) and but a particular if else block never executes in my code and I cant figure why. Here is the code. I'm new to python and I think i'm making a noob mistake but I just figure what it is.

```
class Solution:
def findDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
    left, right = 1, len(nums) - 1
    while left < right :
        mid = left + (right-left)//2
        count = 0
        print("l,r -->" + str(left) + ',' + str(right))
        print("mid -->" + str(mid))
        for k in nums :
            if mid < k <= right: # this block never executes. 
                print(k)
                count += 1
            print("count -->" + str(count))
            if count > right -mid:
                left = mid + 1
            else :
                right = mid
    return right
```

Comment: Print values of mid, k and right on the line before and you'll probably see.

Comment: I think your error is tied to the fact that `mid` and `right` are indices, but `k` is a value in the list.

Comment: values in the list of size n, are between 1 to n. . The code tries to find the duplicate element.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, this

```
if mid < k <= right: # this block never executes.
```

is not doing what you think it is -- instead, you want

```
if mid < k and k <= right:
```